# beginner question to moveit2

Tags: ros2, moveit

I have an issue with moving my arm, I created a script to move to a goal, and for some reason, some poses are working but some are not, what could possibly the problem?
what I did to test is move the arm at some  Goal State using RVIZ2, and then try to tf2_echo from world to the end_link and then get the coordinates, input it in the script.
btw, I use joint_trajectory_controller

here is the output of the script (hello_moveit) I made:

```
[INFO]  [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'robot_arm'...
[INFO]  [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[WARN] [moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[INFO] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group manipulator.
[INFO] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[INFO]  [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[INFO]  [move_group_interface]: Planning request aborted
[ERROR] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::plan() failed or timeout reached
[ERROR] [hello_moveit]: Planing failed!
```

and here is the movegroup launch log

```
[move_group-1] [INFO] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-1] [INFO] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'manipulator' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [ompl]: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-ompl-1.5.2/src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/src/RRTConnect.cpp:253 - manipulator/manipulator: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree
[move_group-1] [INFO] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Unable to solve the planning problem
[move_group-1] [INFO] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: No motion plan found. No execution attempted.
```

as the error says "

> Unable to solve the planning problem"

, somehow, if I manually adjust the joints in this same pose in rviz, planning is success and executed, but if I use the hello_moveit script it is failing.

Comment: > _"for some reason, some poses are working but some are not, what could possibly the problem?"_


Those points are probably out of the workspace or unreachable due to arm collision etc.

Comment: thank you for responding, I see, however is it supposed to act that way ? as I noted at the end, 
***somehow, if I manually adjust the joints in this same pose in rviz, planning is success and executed, but if I use the hello_moveit script it is failing.***
can you please give me an idea as well with how can I execute if for example this arm is attached to a mobile base and i want to pick something in some area. is it possible that the moveit2 module can accommodate this? or I'll have to use the navigtaion stack in addition?.

Comment: I think I messed up the configurations. please help me clarify my thoughts, I now get your point ***points are probably out of the workspace***, since I am attaching this arm in a mobile base, what should be the srdf and xacro def in the move_group? I initially input the whole robot_model and then setup a group name arm in srdf;.

Comment: `<robot name="mobile_base_and_arm">
     <group name="arm">
        <chain base_link="arm_base" tip_link="end_link"/>
     </group>
     <virtual_joint name="world_joint" type="planar" parent_frame="odom" child_link="base_footprint"/>
     <passive_joint name="world_joint" />
     <disable_collisions links=to_all_links_of_mobile_base_and_arm/>...`

Comment: and now the workspace is in the odom's ref, I suspect it is the virtual joint that does that, in that sense how can i set this workspace with respect to the arm_base? because the virtual_joint only accepts this config. if any then this occurs,
`[moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Skipping virtual joint 'world_joint' because its 
      child frame 'arm_base' does not match the URDF frame 'base_footprint'`